# Passing value in a function without quote T-SQL / SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2012, isnumeric

I need assistance with a function in SQL Server 2012 that I created to check for the input value. If the functions detects a numeric - return 0, if detect character return 1.

But I get 2 different result for the same number passing it with quote and without quote.

```
select dbo.IS_ALIEN('56789')
```

returns 0

```
select dbo.IS_ALIEN(56789)
```

returns 1 (I need to return 0)

This is my function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[IS_ALIEN] 
    (@alienNAIC CHAR(1))
RETURNS NUMERIC(10,0) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nNum NUMERIC(1,0);

    BEGIN
        SET @NnUM = ISNUMERIC(@alienNAIC)
    END
    BEGIN
        IF @nNum = 1 
            RETURN 0;
        END

        RETURN 1;
    END
```

Same concept for:

```
select  dbo.IS_ALIEN('AA-11990043')
```

returns 1

or

```
select  dbo.IS_ALIEN(NULL)
```

returns 1 (I need it to return 0)

I'm using Oracle function reference (below code is just reference from old database):

```
create or replace FUNCTION "IS_ALIEN" 
  (  alienNAIC IN char )
  RETURN  NUMBER IS
  nNum number;
BEGIN
    SELECT MOD(alienNAIC, 2) into nNum FROM dual;
    return 0;
EXCEPTION
WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
    return 1;
END;
```

But T-SQL function doesn't allow make exception of error. So I try to converted as much closer.

Comment: Tip: Run `SELECT CAST(56789 As CHAR(1))` in management studio and check the result. This is a problem with Sql Server doing the conversion to your argument type before any of your code even runs. It sounds like you need to work something out using the `sql_variant` type, and that's not gonna be easy.

Comment: ahh i get an asterisk (*)

Comment: Always specify the version of server using tags. if you are using 2008 and later, you can use ISNUMERIC function. BTW, when you define @alienNAIC char(1) as parameter, it only takes the first character of input.

Comment: thanks I modify the title it is sql server 2012. Yes Im trying to check if is null, number or letters. that field will receive a Null or a Number or AA. so If is AA it is an alien so return 1. if is number or null it means is not an alien return 0. But im not getting those results like I do in Oracle.

Comment: Looks like you are using Oracle, but you have tagged with tsql. BTW if the purpose is to check alien, you just need to check for the first 2 letter and make sure they are "AA". then remove the "AA-" and make sure the remaining part is a number. I'm not sure why you have this approach for achieve this. please fix the tags.

Comment: Is all in T-SQL im not using Oracle. The oracle tags is from an old oracle funtion database that I'm using for reference, so Im trying to replicate it using T-SQL. I will try to do a substring to look for the first 2 space as you mention 'AA' and then remove it. thanks.

Comment: @JoelJacobson instead of trying to use an unrelated database as reference, explain what you actually want to do. Not how you tried to do it. Your code has quite a few problems, like the `char(1)` parameter or the `number(1,0)` variable. An IF where none is needed. Are you trying to retrieve the first character with through the parameter instead of using `LEFT`? Why?

Comment: @JoelJacobson SQL Server has PARSE and TRY_PARSE functions. It doesn't *need* exceptions to check whether something can't be parsed. Describe the actual problem, not the attempt to solve it. What is `IS_ALIEN` supposed to do, and what kind of inputs is it supposed to accept?

Comment: @JoelJacobson as for "value without quote", that's not a value without quote. It's an integer. When you pass an integer to a string parameter, SQL Server *has* to cast it to a string. You asked for a *single digit char* though, which makes it impossible. Just *don't* use such a function. If you want to trim the parameter, trim the parameter. Or use LIKE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use something like this (I've trimmed it down somewhat):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[IS_ALIEN](@alienNAIC NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT -- NOTE: You could also return tinyint or bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF ISNUMERIC(@alienNAIC) = 1 
        RETURN 0;

    RETURN 1;
END
```

The trouble with what you were trying is that there's an implicit cast to `CHAR(1)`, the result of which is definitely not numeric as @Joel pointed out:

```
SELECT CAST(0 As CHAR(1)) -- returns character '0', ISNUMERIC(0) = 1
SELECT CAST(9 As CHAR(1)) -- returns character '9', ISNUMERIC(0) = 1
SELECT CAST(12345 As CHAR(1)) -- any number over 9 returns character '*', ISNUMERIC(12345) = 0
```

It's an odd implicit casting case I hadn't seen before.  By making the parameter an `NVARCHAR` (assumes possible future double-byte input), strings will be correctly checked and integers passed in will be implicitly cast as `NVARCHAR`, and the `ISNUMERIC` check will succeed.

**EDIT**
Re-reading the question and comments, it looks like you want to identify a particular string syntax to determine if something is an "alien" or not.  If you're comfortable *changing business logic to fix what apparently is a poor legacy implementation*, you could consider something like this instead:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[temp](@alienNAIC NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT -- NOTE: You could also return tinyint or bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF @alienNAIC like 'AA-%' AND ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(@alienNAIC, LEN(@alienNAIC) - 3)) = 1
        RETURN 1; -- notice this is now 1 instead of 0, we're doing a specific check for 'AA-nnnnn...'

    RETURN 0;
END
```

Note that this should be thoroughly tested against legacy data if it's ever to interact with it - you never know what rubbish data a poorly written legacy system has left behind.  Fixing this could well break other things.  If you do make this change, document it well.

Comment: Thank you for this fix change. It is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check just the first character then you can do like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IS_ALIEN] 
    (@alienNAIC VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS TINYINT 
AS
BEGIN
    IF LEFT(@alienNAIC,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' RETURN 1;
    RETURN 0
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to check whether a string starts with a non-numeric character. Such pattern matches can be performed using [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), eg

```
declare @var nvarchar(10)='A56789'

select 
    case when @var LIKE '[0-9]%' 
         then 0 else 1 
    end AS IsAlien
```

Returns

```
1
```

Both `declare @var nvarchar(10)=56789` and `declare @var int=56789` return 0 because the number is implicitly converted to a string.

The expression is so short that you probably don't need to convert it to a function. If you do, it could be as simple as :

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[IS_ALIEN]  (@alienNAIC varchar(200))
RETURNS INT 
begin 
    return  case when @alienNAIC LIKE '[0-9]%' 
                             then 0 else 1 
                        end 

end
```

If you want to perform the check in a WHERE clause, just use `LIKE`, not any function, eg:

```
WHERE alienNAIC NOT LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

This particular pattern is just a range search that covers all values between `0` and `9......`. The server can use an index that covers the text column to quickly identify the matches. It can't do so when it has to check the *result* of a function. It will have to calculate the value for every single row before filtering.